# How to pass imported module in default props in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to import Avatar svg and try to provide it to default props, I don't know is it the right way to do that as it's not working with below code

```
import Avatar from './avatar.svg';   

export const Upload = ({url}) => {

 return(
<>
  //Not Working
  <img src={url} />

  //Working
  <img src={Avatar} />
</>)}

Upload.defaultProps = {
      url: Avatar
};
```

Comment: so how you call Upload component?

Comment: I'm using storybook, and in that I call Upload something like this

const UploadForm = (args) =>  <Upload {...args} />; 

export const Default = UploadForm.bind({});
Default.args = {
  label: 'Profile pic',
  url: Avatar
};

Comment: is it possible for you to host the code in https://codesandbox.io/ or any other cloud editor?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using default parameters and avoid using `defaultProps`. `defaultProps` will eventually be deprecated on functional components.

You could do something like the following:

```
import Avatar from './avatar.svg';   

export const Upload = ({ url = Avatar }) => {
  return (
     <img src={url} />
  )
}
```